is it possible to debug chrome.sync.storage using unpacked extensions on two PCs?
Debugging chrome extension user prefs sync across PCs:
I can see my extension's user prefs changes syncing between two machines, as immediate "Notified types: Extension settings" updates in chrome://sync-internals/ on the opposite PC.
But this update on the target PC does not fire chrome.storage.onChanged listener in the extension.
The listener does fire when changes are made in either extension locally.
Is there a different mechanism to detect synchronization?
Or, are the two extensions not registered as the same, because they are unpacked?
If so, is there some sort of ID or hash I can use to tell sync that the two extensions under test are the same?
Or a way to package them locally to distribute and debug?
I can't imagine how hard it would be to test and debug this mechanism it it only works with published extensions.

The id is shown in chrome://extensions page and to ensure it's the same you should either put the extension in the same disk+path or calculate key as shown here (see the "not published" section).

Thank you @wOxxOm for the advice and links! I wish the process were inbuilt, but it worked when I:

packaged using button in chrome's extensions panel
uploaded to https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/ and read the public key in the package
added the key to the manifest as per crxviewer
used this same code on all PCs
Hey presto, user prefs syncing now works!
I removed the ID again before submitting to the store

